Lower bound for $\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}$?
Notation: Here I take $\sigma_x(n)$ to mean $\displaystyle{\sum_{d|n}} d^{x}$.
Is there a good lower bound known for $\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}$?
I've seen this post on the average order of this function: The average order of $\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}$, but what about the function itself?
I guess a trivial lower bound would be using the AM-GM inequality: $\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n) } \geq \sqrt[\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)]{d_1 ...d_{\sigma_0(n)}} =  \sqrt[\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)]{n^{\frac{ \scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}{2}}} = \sqrt{n}$. Can we do better?
Thanks.

Note that this ratio is $\prod_{p^r \parallel n} \frac{p^{r + 1} - 1}{r(p - 1)} = n \prod_{p^r \parallel n} \frac{1 - p^{-r - 1}}{r(1 - p^{-1})}$, and the latter product is $\gg_{\varepsilon} n^{-\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

@PeterHumphries It's $r+1$ in the denominator.

Note that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $C_{\epsilon}>0$ st $\sigma_0(n) \le C_{\epsilon}n^{\epsilon}$; since trivially $\sigma_1(n) \ge n$ it follows that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $K_{\epsilon}>0$ st $\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)} \ge K_{\epsilon}n^{1-\epsilon}$; by considering $n=2^k$ it is easily seen that one cannot have $\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)} \ge Kn$

Yes,we can do better. We can prove, for example
$$\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}\ge\frac{7}{3\sqrt[3]{18}}\ n^{2/3}$$
with equality if and only if $n=12$.
This can be generalized to prove bounds of the form
$$\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}\ge C_\delta \ n^\delta$$
for any $\delta<1$.

Hey, thanks for the response! Any chance you could include or provide the reference for the proof of this statement?

I don't know any reference for the statement, but you can try to prove it by considering the function $\frac{\sigma_1(p^a)}{p^{2/3 a}\sigma_0(p^a)}$ as a function of $a$ for each $p$.

(Reposting cause I made an error on first comment). I think I sort of understand where you're coming from, but not completely. Similar to what @PeterHumphries wrote, if $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} ... p_r^{\alpha_r}$, then $\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}  = \displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{r}} \dfrac{p_i^{\alpha_i + 1} - 1}{(p_i - 1)(\alpha_i + 1)}$, which by the Mean Value Theorem, $ = \displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{r}} \xi_i^{\alpha_i} $, for some $\xi_i \in (1, p_i)$. (cont. in next comment for space).

Thus, there exists an $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$, s.t. $ \displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{r}} \xi_i^{\alpha_i} \geq \epsilon^{r} \displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{r}} p_i^{a_i} = \epsilon^{r} n$? I feel like I'm on the wrong track though and not seeing how the  $p^{2/3 \alpha}$ in the denominator comes into play. Also, I think I may have erred somewhere as I should be getting some $n^{\delta}$, where $\delta < 1$, as opposed to some constant times $ n$ but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

I'll look at @Conrad 's comment to try to "debug" my response.

Turns out I answered this in 2013
Bounds on the average of the divisors of natural numbers.
and again in 2015, gave the sequence a name  and put it on OEIS
https://oeis.org/A263572
but I did not go as far as finding asymptotics  at the time
Takes a while to work out such asymptotics:
$$\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}\ge n^{\left(\; 1 \; - \; \frac{0.88818710981202113663349540540042873583}{\log \log n} \; \right)}  $$
with equality at one point only,
$$   n = 69292345589126960972049123209194899168000 $$
where $  \log_{10}  n \approx    40.8406852627214 $
and
$$ n = 2^8 \cdot 3^5  \cdot 5^3  \cdot    7^2  \cdot 11^2  \cdot 13^2  \cdot 17  \cdot 19  \cdot 23  \cdot 29  \cdot 31  \cdot 37  \cdot 41  \cdot 43  \cdot 47  \cdot 53  \cdot 59  \cdot 61  \cdot 67  \cdot 71  \cdot 73  \cdot 79  \cdot 83  \cdot 89 $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}\ge n^{\left(\; 1 \; - \; \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \;  - \; \frac{1.035350740283634}{(\log \log n)^2}   \right)}  $$
with equality at one point $n$ only,
where $  \log_{10}  n \approx    241.1487971056956 $
and  $$ n = 2^{12} \cdot 3^7 \cdot  5^5 \cdot  7^4 \cdot  11^3 \cdot  13^3 \cdot  17^2 \cdot  19^2 \cdot  23^2 \cdot  29^2 \cdot  31^2 \cdot  37^2 \cdot  41 \cdot  43 \cdots  \cdots 503  \cdot 509 \cdot  521 \cdot  523 $$
